# MVC 3 System.Web.Optimization Bundles single file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, bundle, asp.net-4.5, asp.net-optimization

In MVC3 C# I'm trying the new System.Web.Optimization Bundles JSminify & CssMinify package (part of the .NET 4.5 framework).

I have one main Bundle. On one page in my website, I wish to include a single .js file only for that page. I would like to have it minified like the bundles, but it does not need to be bundled.

How can this be done?

- Also, is the source and documentation available for this package?

Comment: You can give this library a go https://github.com/vincpa/mvc.resourceloader

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to add another bundle to it.

For example:

```
Bundle myJSBundle = new Bundle("~/combined-scripts/custom/my-page", 
                                                               typeof(JsMinify));
myJSBundle.AddFile("~/Scripts/Custom/MyPage.js");
```

Then in your page:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/combined-scripts/custom/my-page")" 
                                                 type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Reference:
- http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2011/12/bundling-and-minification-aspnet-mvc4.html

More readings:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/11/27/new-bundling-and-minification-support-asp-net-4-5-series.aspx

Comment: This is correct. I wrote about that here: http://jclaes.blogspot.com/2012/02/aspnet-mvc4-bundling-in-aspnet-mvc3.html